# Why do I get an OverflowException when using Graphics.ScaleTransform?

Tags: c#, winforms, scaletransform, overflowexception

I have some drawing code for an editor I am working on. It draws a few lines and an image buffer. After adding a zoom features and calling `ScaleTransform` I get an `OverflowException` thrown in my paint method.

Is something being scaled outside the bounds? My scaling factor is `2.0` and I have even tried `1.0` and making sure all the window sizes / buffers are large enough.

Answer (score 0):

The `Graphics.Transform` property is not reset to the identity matrix. You have to do this yourself at the beginning of your paint method:

```
g.Tranfsorm = new Matrix();
g.ScaleTransform(2.0, 2.0);
```

Otherwise after a few exponents it will overflow (at 60 frames per second as in my application this would seem instantaneous)

Comment: Hmm, no, the underlying problem is that you use CreateGraphics() instead of using the Paint event.  So you'll have to take care of  properly restoring it after you're done.  Use its Save() and Restore() methods instead.  It is very rarely correct to use CreateGraphics but at 60 fps its okay.

Comment: You're wrong because I don't use `CreateGraphics` :)